# Storing elapsed time data in an array inside a for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, time, store, elapsedtime

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <ctime>

std::stack<clock_t> tictoc_stack;   
void tic() {
   tictoc_stack.push(clock());
}
void toc() {
   std::cout << "Time elapsed: "
   << ((double)(clock() - tictoc_stack.top())) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC
   << std::endl;
   tictoc_stack.pop();
   dif=(clock() - tictoc_stack.top())    
}

int main()
{
   tic();
   for (k=0;k<10;k++)
   {
     doSomething();
     toc();
     double t[10];
     for(i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
       t[i]=dif;
       std::cout<< "array is" << dif << std::endl;
     }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Now, when I call the `toc()` func it gives the elapsed time. but I want that time to go into an array at each iteration. which means I would have 10 different elapsed time and I want to get these values and calculate the mean, min, max and standard deviation.

So far I am having a hard time getting the elapsed to be stored in the array every time the loop goes around.

Any Suggestions and help.

Comment: PLEASE INDENT YOUR CODE PROPERLY.

Answer (score 0):

You `tic()` once, which means you `push` once. But you `toc()` multiple times which means you `pop` multiple times.